# http request (using net http or RestClient) inside my rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest-client, net-http

I  have problem creating http request inside my controller action. I used net/http and RestClient but I can't get it to work on my local server url i.e http://localhost:3000/engine/do_process, I always get requesttimeout however It works with other valid url.

Hope you can enlighten me on this one. I did some research but I can't find resources as to why I got this timeout problem.

Sample controller code:

```
require 'rest_client'

class LgController < ApplicationController
  def get_lgjson

     response =  RestClient.get("http://localhost:3000/engine/do_process_lg")
     @generated_json = response.to_str

  end
end
```

Comment: Show us the code to create the request please. My money is on that you're making another HTTP request to another part of your application and because WEBrick being a single-threaded server it's not able to serve it at the same time as the initial request.

Comment: require 'rest_client'
class LgController < ApplicationController
  ef get_lgjson
     
     response =  RestClient.get("http://localhost:3000/engine/do_process_lg")
     @generated_json = response.to_str
    
  end
 end

Comment: I always get request timeout problem, not sure why.

Comment: What Ryan Bigg said: "it's not able to serve it at the same time as the initial request".  That means RestClient#get cannot be responded to until your get_lgjson controller action finishes (i.e. never)....  You want a multi threaded server, or maybe run two instances on different ports.

Comment: @adzdavies thanks for the reply. I think i need a multi threaded server. Its my first time coding RoRs, i don't know which way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem today, too, exactly in the same context: using the [Ruby RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to make a HTTP request inside a controller. It worked earlier in a different project using [OpenURI](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/OpenURI) without problems. This was surprising because both http libraries, the RestClient and OpenURI for Ruby, [use the same library Net::HTTP](http://jvns.ca/blog/2016/03/04/whats-up-with-ruby-http-libraries/).

It is the URL that makes the difference. We can make a connection to an external URL in the controller, but not to localhost. The problem seems to be the duplicated connection to localhost. There is already a connection to localhost open, and we are trying to open a second one. This does not seem to work in a single-threaded web server like [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) for instance. A multi-threaded web server such as [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you use single-threaded web server. You have two opportunities to fix.

1. use passenger
2. define if it makes sense to make net/http to localhost.